# PHP and XML: Need to retrieve values inside "multidimensional" xml structure, where tags have the same names

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an object, that has some xml metadata as a property named MetadataXML. I need to grab the values inside the xml tags and store them in php variables. I have succeeded doing it on this xml structure:

```
[MetadataXML] =>

"<metadata>

     <title>A title</titel>
     <body>Some text in the body</body>

 </metadata>"
```

with this code :

```
$meta = simplexml_load_string($object->MetadataXML);

$title = (string)$meta->title;
$body  = (string)$meta->body;
```

But now I have a xml structure that looks like this:

```
<metadata>

    <two_related_books>

        <book>
            <id>20</id>
            <title>A title</title>
        </book>

        <book>
            <id>55</id>
            <title>Another title</title>
        </book>

    </two_related_books>

</metadata>
```

I have tried to loop through the book items in several different ways, to somehow get the values inside the id and title tags for each book. But have been unsuccessful in retrieving anything. I have also tried using XPath.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$meta = simplexml_load_string( $object->MetadataXML);
foreach( $meta->two_related_books->book as $book) {
    echo $book->id;
    echo $book->title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, when I do that, I get an 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' error?

Comment: @krismeld - That's strange because [**I don't**](http://viper-7.com/mhmPo1).

Comment: You are right, thanks. Now I found the error. When I did a print_f($meta) it revealed that two_related_books was actually called two_related_Books. I had no idea that it could differ from the name you can see when inspecting the data through Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

For these tash, it is better use DOMDocument and XPath object.

Base example:

```
// Load XML
$dom = new \DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xmlData);

// Create a new XPath object
$domXPath = new \DOMXPath($dom);

$bookItems = $domXpath->evaluate('//book'); // Or "/metadata/two_related_books/book", fot get from root node
// Or
$bookItems = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('book');

foreach ($bookItems as $item) {
  // Here code for control each item
}
```